# mutate/transform in R dplyr (Pass custom function)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the new package , dplyr and facing some difficulties.

```
mutate(df,isOdd=digit%%2) or transform(df,isOdd=digit%%2)
```

Both of which work perfectly.

I am asking a question on passing custom method.

```
IsItOdd <- function(x) {
  if(x%%2==0)
     result<-"even"
  else
     result<-"odd"
  return(result)
}

transform(df,isOdd=IsItOdd(digit))
```

This doesnt work because the whole column of all the digit is passed to the function. 
Is there a way to make this work by just passing that one cell to the function instead of the whole column ?

Comment: `transform(df,isOdd=vapply(digit, IsItOdd, ""))` or `transform(df,isOdd=Vectorize(IsItOdd)(digit))`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With transform your function has to operate on the vector. You can use `ifelse` instead, which works on vectors:

```
 isOdd <- function(x){ ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, "even", "odd") }
```

Alternatively you can apply the function to every value in the column with one of the `apply` functions:

```
 isOdd <- function(x){
     sapply(x, function(x){
          if(x %% 2 == 0){
               return("even") 
          }else{
               return("odd") 
          }
     })}
```

Comment: Can you explain why with transform/mutate the function operates on the entire vector rather than on the individual values? This isn't true with base functions (e.g. sin() or log()).

Comment: @rmcd I'm very interested in your question, maybe worth another thread?  I guess `dplyr::mutate` is parsing the function and trying to guess whether to pass in a single value or the whole vector?

Comment: btw you can force the proper behavior by using `dplyr::rowwise` but it's still an interesting question

Comment: @WillCornwell Thanks for the response and the pointer to rowwise, which I was't aware of. I've posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967559/why-is-r-dplyrmutate-inconsistent-with-custom-functions

Answer (score 9):

I think you could also use group_by() to tease apart the rows by unique values and subsequently do your computation, like so:

```
df %>% group_by(digit) %>% mutate(isOdd = IsItOdd(digit))
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use mutate, you can do it in R base or in purr

```
get_rango_edad <- function(x) {
    if (x <= 25) {
       return("18-25")
     } else{
        return("26+")
     }
  }

encuestas$rango_edad <- map_chr(encuestas$edad,get_rango_edad)
```

or

```
encuestas$rango_edad <- sapply(encuestas$edad,get_rango_edad)
```