# Why is R dplyr::mutate inconsistent with custom functions

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is a "why", not a how. In the following code I'm trying to understand why `dplyr::mutate` evaluates one custom function (`f()`) with the entire vector but not with the other custom function (`g()`).  What exactly is `mutate` doing?

```
set.seed(1);sum(rnorm(100, c(0, 10, 100)))
f=function(m) {
    set.seed(1)
    sum(rnorm(100, mean=m))
}
g <- function(m) sin(m)
df <- data.frame(a=c(0, 10, 100))
y1 <- mutate(df, asq=a^2, fout=f(a), gout=g(a))
y2 <- rowwise(df) %>%
    mutate(asq=a^2, fout=f(a), gout=g(a))
y3 <- group_by(df, a) %>%
    summarize(asq=a^2, fout=f(a), gout=g(a))
```

For all three columns, `asq`, `fout`, and `gout`, evaluation is rowwise in `y2` and `y3` and the results are identical. However, `y1$fout` is 3640.889 for all three rows, which is the result of evaluating `sum(rnorm(100, c(0, 10, 100)))`. So the function `f()` is evaluating the entire vector for each row.

A closely related question has been asked elsewhere [mutate/transform in R dplyr (Pass custom function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579361/mutate-transform-in-r-dplyr-pass-custom-function), but the "why" was not explained.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sin` and `^` are vectorized, so they natively operate on each individual value, rather than on the whole vector of values. `f` is not vectorized. But you can do `f = Vectorize(f)` and it will operate on each individual value as well.

```
y1 <- mutate(df, asq=a^2, fout=f(a), gout=g(a))
y1
```

> ```
>     a   asq     fout       gout
> 1   0     0 3640.889  0.0000000
> 2  10   100 3640.889 -0.5440211
> 3 100 10000 3640.889 -0.5063656
> ```

```
f = Vectorize(f)

y1a <- mutate(df, asq=a^2, fout=f(a), gout=g(a))
y1a
```

> ```
>     a   asq        fout       gout
> 1   0     0    10.88874  0.0000000
> 2  10   100  1010.88874 -0.5440211
> 3 100 10000 10010.88874 -0.5063656
> ```

Some additional info on vectorization [here](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html), [here](https://deanattali.com/blog/mutate-non-vectorized/), and [here](https://www.jimhester.com/post/2018-04-12-vectorize/).

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. The links on vectorization are on point. My mental model was that mutate was implicitly doing a loop, but if I understand correctly it's not, it's passing a vector. This makes sense and explains the differing results in my example.

Answer (score 2):

We can loop through each element of 'a' using `map` and apply the function `f`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(asq = a^2, fout = map_dbl(a, f), gout = g(a)) 
#    a   asq        fout       gout
#1   0     0    10.88874  0.0000000
#2  10   100  1010.88874 -0.5440211
#3 100 10000 10010.88874 -0.5063656
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution follows [Jim Hester's recommendation](http://www.jimhester.com/2018/04/12/vectorize/), the third link in the answer I accepted.