# Different results if I run a function with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with people belonging to groups, one person can be mentioned several times with name variations and different person_id. My plan is to compare inside each group the values of person_name and compute a score that gives me an idea of the similarities, so I could put together all the person_id belonging to one person.

Here a sample:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  group_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  person_id = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8),
  person_name = c("Smith, J.", "Areta Franklin", "John Smith", "Robert Mitchum", "Robert Mitchum", "Cary Grant", "John Rambo", "Martin Sheen", "Rambo John")
)
```

dt

```
  group_id person_id    person_name
1        1         1      Smith, J.
2        1         2 Areta Franklin
3        1         3     John Smith
4        2         4 Robert Mitchum
5        2         4 Robert Mitchum
6        2         5     Cary Grant
7        3         6     John Rambo
8        3         7   Martin Sheen
9        3         8     Rambo John
```

I tried the following

```
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)

simil_names <- function(name1, name2) {
  name1 <- gsub("[^A-z0-9 ]","",tolower(name1))
  name2 <- gsub("[^A-z0-9 ]","",tolower(name2))
  name1.v <- sort(unlist(strsplit(name1," ")))
  name2.v <- sort(unlist(strsplit(name2," ")))
  dist <- 0
  if (length(name1.v) == length(name2.v)) {
    # In this case we have the same number of words between the 2 strings
    # Therefore we will check for each word if it's the same or if the first letter is the same
    for(i in c(1:length(name1.v))) {
      if ((nchar(name1.v[i]) == 1 || nchar(name2.v[i]) == 1) && nchar(name1.v[i]) + nchar(name2.v[i]) > 2) {
        # Case of "j" in one string and "jeff" in the other string
        # we compare only the first letter, if it's the same then the distance is 0, otherwise we compute the full Damerau-Levenshtein distance
        if (substr(name1.v[i],1,1) != substr(name2.v[i],1,1)) {
          dist <- dist + stringdist(name1.v[i],name2.v[i], method = 'dl')
        }
      } else {
        # Case of 2 words of more than one letter
        dist <- dist + stringdist(name1.v[i],name2.v[i], method = 'dl')
      }
    }
  } else {
    # Here we compare both strings in alphabetical order
    dist.a <- stringdist(paste(name1.v, collapse = " "),paste(name2.v, collapse = " "), method = 'dl')
    dist.n <- stringdist(name1,name2, method = 'dl')
    dist <- min(c(dist.a,dist.n))
  }
  return(dist)
}

dt2 <- unique(inner_join(dt,dt, by = c("group_id"), multiple = "all") %>% filter(person_id.x > person_id.y) %>% mutate(score = simil_names(person_name.x, person_name.y)))
```

I expect to get this result

```
  group_id person_id.x  person_name.x person_id.y  person_name.y score
1        1           2 Areta Franklin           1      Smith, J.    13
2        1           3     John Smith           1      Smith, J.     0
3        1           3     John Smith           2 Areta Franklin    13
4        2           5     Cary Grant           4 Robert Mitchum    11
5        3           7   Martin Sheen           6     John Rambo    10
6        3           8     Rambo John           6     John Rambo     0
7        3           8     Rambo John           7   Martin Sheen    10
```

However, I get

```
  group_id person_id.x  person_name.x person_id.y  person_name.y score
1        1           2 Areta Franklin           1      Smith, J.    64
2        1           3     John Smith           1      Smith, J.    64
3        1           3     John Smith           2 Areta Franklin    64
4        2           5     Cary Grant           4 Robert Mitchum    64
5        3           7   Martin Sheen           6     John Rambo    64
6        3           8     Rambo John           6     John Rambo    64
7        3           8     Rambo John           7   Martin Sheen    64
```

I do not understand why, when I execute the function with mutate, the results is different.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The reason is ```simil_names``` is not vectorized. The simplest solution is to add ```rowwise()``` before ```mutate```.

Comment: dplyr assumes your function is vectorized. That is, if you pass in multiple values, it needs to return a vector of the same length as output. Normall dplyr passed in entire columns at a time to a function because that's faster. But you can use `rowwise()` to make it operate a row at a time. Or you can use `Vectorize()` to vectorize your function. More references here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967559/why-is-r-dplyrmutate-inconsistent-with-custom-functions

Answer (score 1):

Since OP has tagged `dplyr`, a `tidyverse` strategy to do this.  May be this can be of help too.

Explanation-

- In the first part we have created combination of two names (sorted person_id wise so that person with lower id will always be on left side) and untested the data.
- In second part we have brought the strings i.e. person names.
- Lastly, we have calculated the distance.

All this in one pipeline

```r
library(tidyverse)

dt <- data.frame(
  group_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  person_id = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8),
  person_name = c("Smith, J.", "Areta Franklin", "John Smith", "Robert Mitchum", "Robert Mitchum", "Cary Grant", "John Rambo", "Martin Sheen", "Rambo John")
)

dt %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  arrange(person_id) %>% 
  summarise(persons = list(unique(person_id)), .by = group_id) %>% 
  mutate(persons = map(persons, ~ combn(.x, 2) %>% 
                         `rownames<-`(paste0("person", 1:2)) %>% 
                         t() %>% 
                         as_tibble()
                       )) %>% 
  unnest(persons) %>% 
  left_join(dt %>% 
              distinct() %>% 
              rename(person1_name = person_name),
            by = join_by(group_id == group_id, person1 == person_id),
            relationship = "many-to-one") %>% 
  left_join(dt %>% 
              distinct() %>% 
              rename(person2_name = person_name),
            by = join_by(group_id == group_id, person2 == person_id),
            relationship = "many-to-one") %>% 
  mutate(score = stringdist::stringdist(person1_name, person2_name, method = "dl"))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#>   group_id person1 person2 person1_name   person2_name   score
#>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>          <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1        1       1       2 Smith, J.      Areta Franklin    13
#> 2        1       1       3 Smith, J.      John Smith         9
#> 3        1       2       3 Areta Franklin John Smith        13
#> 4        2       4       5 Robert Mitchum Cary Grant        12
#> 5        3       6       7 John Rambo     Martin Sheen      10
#> 6        3       6       8 John Rambo     Rambo John        10
#> 7        3       7       8 Martin Sheen   Rambo John         9
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @one and @MrFlick for the answers and the references.

I ended up creating a function with `simil_names.v <- Vectorize(simil_names)` and it now works as expected.